# Warming up in machine learning using python

Tags: python

We have a machine learning project about classification. At first, I have tried an easiest classifier: An classifier always predicts +1.
Here is my code.

```
from binary import *
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

import util
import datasets
import binary
import dumbClassifiers

class AlwaysPredictOne(BinaryClassifier):
    """
    This defines the classifier that always predicts +1.
    """

    def __init__(self, opts):
        """
        do nothing
        """

    def online(self):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return "AlwaysPredictOne"

    def predict(self, X):
        return 1       # return our constant prediction

    def train(self, X, Y):
        """
        do nothing
        """
h = dumbClassifiers.AlwaysPredictOne({})

print(h)

h.train(datasets.TennisData.X, datasets.TennisData.Y)

h_p = h.predictAll(datasets.TennisData.X)

print(h_p)

m = mean((datasets.TennisData.Y > 0) == (h.predictAll(datasets.TennisData.X) > 0))
print(m)

t = mean((datasets.TennisData.Yte > 0) == (h.predictAll(datasets.TennisData.Xte) > 0))

print(t)
```

Then the result:

```
AlwaysPredictOne
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
0.642857142857
0.5

AlwaysPredictOne

[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
0.642857142857
0.5
```

Although the answer is right, my question is why it appears twice?? Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: How you run the code, Something is missing here.

Comment: I recommend to replace the "do nothing" comments by *pass*: why use a comment, when there is syntax available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code is *Ipsis Verbis* but this would happen if you were importing the same script you would be running (running its contents twice).

One small example. Lets say I make a file called `example.py` and write the following inside:

```
import example

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Running Example __init__")

ex = Example()
```

Notice how I'm importing the file itself in my very first instruction? Well the result is the following:

```
Running Example __init__
Running Example __init__
```

Put your running script separately from your objects, avoid self-importing, and you should do fine.

Comment: Thanks! I separate them, then everything goes well!